# Shopify Remove Parcel Tracking (RCT Track17) on Thank You/Order Status Page

Tags: shopify

Where does this tracking button on the order status page that opens the below iframe come from and how to disable it?

[image order status page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZY4C.png)

I can't find the App that adds this funtionality, is there any way to remove it?

Also my CSS doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the tracking button that is displayed depending on which shipping carrier the customer chooses. If it's on the Order Status page, you will need to ensure that you have the `checkout.liquid` file enabled. You can add some JavaScript to the bottom of that file above the closing `</body>` tag that waits for the DOM to load, selects the element on the page and them removes it.

You can [click here to read more about editing the checkout.liquid on Shopify](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/architecture/layouts/checkout-liquid).

If you don't have access to the `checkout.liquid` file, you can also add some code to the additional checkout scripts box in the Admin (also accepts CSS between style tags). You can [click here to read more about using the additional scripts box in the Admin](https://help.shopify.com/manual/orders/status-tracking/customize-order-status).

With all that said, it also looks like there is an option to disable that in the Shopify Admin, according to a [Shopify community post on disabling the tracking number](https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/disable-order-tracking-on-thank-you-page/m-p/940083/highlight/true#M38252).

I hope that helps.